# Help solving for x.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I cannot figure this out for the life of me. I am getting $x = -7$, $x = 0$.

When I plug it back in, it is not even close to being right. Help please.

> $\displaystyle \frac{42}{x}-\frac{6}{x+7} = \frac{7(x+13)}{x^2+7x}$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck! Here you have a guide to write mathematical expressions with MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $$\displaystyle \frac{42}{x}-\frac{6}{x+7} = \frac{7(x+13)}{x^2+7x}\;,$$ Here $x\neq 0$ and $x\neq -7$

Bcz at $x=0$ and $x=-7,$ Equation is in the form of $\infty = \infty$ and $-\infty = \infty$

So $$\displaystyle 42(x+7)-6x = 7(x+13)\Rightarrow 42x+42\times 7-6x = 7x+13\times 7$$

So we get $$29x=203\Rightarrow x = 7$$

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we have $x\neq 0$ and $x\neq -7$.

Then, we have $$\frac{36x+294}{x(x+7)} = \frac{7(x+13)}{x(x+7)}$$

So $$29x = 203 \Rightarrow x =7.$$